# Android Listview and editText box

Tags: android

My code is as follows

layout1

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

layout 2

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <EditText android:id="@+id/newmessagecontent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:singleLine="false" 
                android:gravity="top" 
                android:layout_width="250dp" 
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                  /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

My java code is

```
public class CheckitoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.row);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        //EditText view = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newmessagecontent);
        //listView.addHeaderView(view, null, true); 
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        });



        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };


        // First paramenter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the View to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

I want the edit box to come up separately first. The user should enter the data and then my app will store the required data into a string array and then display it.How do i go about doing this?

Comment: The editbox is displayed along with the list view. I want the editbox to be displayed only once at the beginning and the listview below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well then you gotta add the EditText as an listview header not listview item

create following code as sep. layout, then add this view to header.

```
<TableLayout   
    android:layout_weight="0"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

    <TableRow>  
        <EditText android:id="@+id/newmessagecontent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:singleLine="false"  
            android:gravity="top"  
            android:layout_width="250dp"  
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
              />  

        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:id="@+id/sendmessage"   
            android:text="Send"   
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            />  
    </Table> 
      </TableLayout>



EditText view = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.....);
listView.addHeaderView(view, null, true);
```

**UPDATE**

here

```
ListView lv = getListView(); 
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, lv, false); //header is above XML code
lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Comment: It keeps throwing an exception at listview.setAdapter(..) when i add the edit text as a header view. I have edited the question.Please atke a look

Comment: you gottoa inflate the header before you add it to list view.

Comment: Can you please tell me the code to do that.What if i wanted to add a button next to the edit box how would i inflate both of them together

Comment: well the above layout does have an button next to EditText